# Convert API to Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have a created a table that use simple JS and an API to pull in info about our Android App. We would like to have this code on multiple pages

```
<div class="api">
<div style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 700px;">
<div style="float: left;">
<table style="background-color: #e7e7e27; border-color: #e2e2e2;">
<td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; background: #e2e2e2; border-top: 0px; ">
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/<!---package name--->" class="no_ul external" target="_blank">
<img src="http://developer.android.com/images/brand/Google_Play_Store_96.png" style="width:90px; border:0" alt="<!---Verbage--->" title="<!---Verbage--->">
</a>
</td>
</table>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<div class='appbrain-app'>
<a href='http://www.appbrain.com/app/<!---package name--->' style='font-size: 11px; color: #555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;'>
</a>
</div> 
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='http://www.appbrain.com/api/api.nocache.js'></script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Not the prettiest code but it does the job that I we are wanting. I would like to turn this into a plugin with a shortcode to reference it. I know that this is probably bigger then I expect and I have a good understanding of HTML and wordpress but this is the first plugin I have created.

Thanks,
Grady

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plugin to do this is fairly trivial since you are just echoing static data.

```
class My_App_Data {

  function __construct() {
    add_shortcode('app_data',array($this,'app_data_shortcode'));
  }

  function app_data_shortcode() { ?>
    <div class="api">
      <div style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 700px;">
    <div style="float: left;">
      <table style="background-color: #e7e7e27; border-color: #e2e2e2;">
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; background: #e2e2e2; border-top: 0px; ">
          <a rel="nofollow" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/<!---package name--->" class="no_ul external" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://developer.android.com/images/brand/Google_Play_Store_96.png" style="width:90px; border:0" alt="<!---Verbage--->" title="<!---Verbage--->">
          </a>
        </td>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
      <div class='appbrain-app'>
        <a href='http://www.appbrain.com/app/<!---package name--->' style='font-size: 11px; color: #555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;'></a>
      </div> 
      <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='http://www.appbrain.com/api/api.nocache.js'></script>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div><?php
  } 
}
new My_App_data();
```

You can now use `[app_data /]` to display the markup.

You will need to construct a [proper plugin header](http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header#Plugin_File_Header_Example), and use a better name for the class :).

### Reference

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin